# Segmentation fault when looping through directories with bash script

Tags: bash, directory

I understand this is usually to do with recursion, except I am pretty sure I am not doing this.
On each time round the loop it gives a segmentation error pointing to the for loop's line.

```
for file in $DATAFOLDER*; do
    echo $file;
    filename=$(basename $file);
    echo $filename;
    echo "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}"
    pwd
    # move data to cppapplication folder
    cp -R "$file" "$DESTFOLDER";
    sleep 1
    # create subdirectory
    mkdir "$SUBFOLDER";
    # create new folder for extracted data
    mkdir "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}";
    # copy MassLynx header file into new folder (get the description info)
    cp "$file/_HEADER.TXT" "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}";
    # run the cppapplication
    # <program> <project file> <MassSpectrum> <Mobilogram> <bins in Da> <extract m/z ranges>
    ./cppapplication.exe "$filename" 0 1 1 0 ;
    # fix last character comma bug
    sed -i '$ s/,$//g' MassMobility.txt
    # move the created files into the new folder
    mv Mobilogram.txt "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}";
    mv MassMobility.txt "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}"; 
    mv MassMobilityXaxis.txt "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}";
    mv MassMobilityYaxis.txt "$DESTFOLDER$SUBFOLDER${filename%%.*}";    
    # get driftscope quicklook image
    sleep 3
    python "C:\Users\ganesh\Dropbox\PhD\03_Amphitrite\CppApplication\quicklook_driftscope.py" "$DESTFOLDERWINDOWS$SUBFOLDERWINDOWS" "${filename%%.*}" "$DESTFOLDERWINDOWS$SUBFOLDERWINDOWS${filename%%.*}";


    # remove MassLynx Project
    rm -r "$filename";

done
```

Aside from the copying of the file, I don't think the loop has any contact with the original folder being looped through.

This is the error:

```
./extract_all_projects.sh: line 26:  7500 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

I have no idea what the problem is as "cppapplication.exe" works fine on these files if run outside of the bash script.

Comment: are you really sure `for file in $DATASTORE*; do ...` is doing what you think. When I do that in a directory, the * doesn't get expanded, I just get the name of the specified dir (the value in DATASTORE). Good luck.

Comment: thanks, yeah I don't want file to be expanded further.

Comment: what debugging have you done? did you check to make sure filename is holding the value you expect?

Comment: good point. So your `echo $filename` never returns anything? Do you know about `set -vx`. Put that near the top of the script and you can see each segment of code before it executes and then each statment with values of variables in place. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$filename` could be empty or not as expected. I'm sure the segfault is the `cppapplication.exe` crashing (Why didn't you tell us what line 26 is?) To test this, try

```
./cppapplication.exe "" 0 1 1 0
```

and see if it segfaults. If I had to guess: the app tries to open a file but doesn't check the return value and soldiers on with a NULL pointer.

BTW, all except the first semicolon in your script are useless. The shell is not C :-)

Comment: line 26 was the "for ..." line, sorry I thought that was clear from the start of the question. Thanks for the semi colon tip and I will check what you suggested